# Take ClickListener time of RecyclerView with livedata

Tags: android

We have taken the event time click of RecyclerView using live data mvvm. All data come from API using retrofit.
Live data fill in RecyclerView. Now listing data set click listener open other screen those detail screen.any help me to set click listener.
I have six classes

- myReqestAdapter
- myRequestModel
- myRequestModelData
- MainViewModel
- RequestRepository
- MyRequestsFragment

Comment: You can dynamically send all data in details page using intent.putExtra()

Comment: You can set a click listener to your holder in adapter and open detail intent from this click listener. Make sure send your data to details intent using myIntent.putExtra()

Comment: you can just use interface here to implement click listener, 
Another way is that you have to take one Mutable live data then post the value on click of any item.

Answer (score 2):

1) In ViewModel, Have a MutableLiveData variable to hold the selected Item.

```
MutableLiveData<Item> selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

2) Observe that LiveData variable in your UI and write the intent code to next screen with item in extras.

```
mViewModel.selectedItem.observe(this, new Observer<Item>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Item item) {
        if (item != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity, NextActivity);
            intent.putExtra(Const.KEY_INTENT_DATA_ITEM, item);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

3) Pass the ViewModel object to your Adapter.

4) Add click listener to your view and From onBindViewHolder you will get item position. Using that, we can get the selected item.

5) On Item Click, set the item to your ViewModel's MutableLiveData variable.

```
mViewModel.selectedItem.setValue(item);
```

6) As we are observing that variable in UI, `onChanged()` will be called and It will show it's data in your next screen.